# rstudio docker ubuntu file persistance problem

Tags: docker, rstudio, persistent-storage, rocker

HI Docker/rocker experts.
Your help would be appreciated. This is driving me nuts.
I've tried a range of things from the web and stack overflow, to no avail.

Ubuntu system with docker desktop installed.

I can't create files in the mounted volume

The docker file is:

```
    FROM rocker/rstudio

MAINTAINER AN

RUN apt-get clean all && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
            libhdf5-dev \
            libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            libxml2-dev \
            libpng-dev \
            libxt-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libbz2-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        libglpk40 \
        libgit2-dev \
        patch \         
            jags \
        && apt-get clean all && \
    apt-get purge && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages(c('MixSIAR', 'ggplot2', 'NMOF', 'tidyverse', 'readxl' ));" 

WORKDIR /home/rstudio
```

The command it is run with is:

> docker run --rm -ti -v "/home/username/IsoMixingModel/":"/home/rstudio/IsoMixingModel/" -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=1234 rstudio:1.0

When I try to create a file within rstudio:

> > setwd("~/IsoMixingModel")
> > df <- data.frame(cat=c(1,2,3,4))
> > write.csv(df, file = "./cat.csv")
> > Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> > cannot open the connection
> > In addition: Warning message:
> > In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> > cannot open file './cat.csv': Permission denied

Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with RStudio but I built your container and ran it. There appears to be no folder `~/IsoMixingModel` and so your first command `setwd("~/IsoMixingModel")` fails. If you `getwd()` immediately, the working folder is `/root`. You can switch to your volume-mounted folder using `setwd(/home/rstudio/IsoMixingModel")` which will then permit you to write the CSV to the host folder.

Comment: **NOTE** Your `docker run` includes `rstudio:1.0` which -- I assume -- is the name you've given to the container image that you built.

Comment: Your docker file ends with `WORKDIR /home/rstudio`. This command has no effect. It changes the working directory of the container build. Even using the `--workdir` flag with `docker run` is unlikely (don't know) to affect the working folder of RStudio.

Comment: thanks for the comments @DazWilkin . I followed a different path and got it working ...Ill post up the answer that worked for me below. Really appreciate you considering the question.

Answer (score 0):

for those curious..
I know exactly this config was working on my colleague's machine. However he was not using Docker desktop.

I uninstalled docker desktop:

> https://docs.docker.com/desktop/uninstall/

Then I deleted the directory ~/.docker

Then I did a fresh docker install.

Then i re ran the docker build -- and it works perfectly.

I don't know what docker desktop was doing, but it seemed to be
complicating things..